# Task Mgmt App, web based, self hosted

Tags: web-apps, project-management, note-taking

I'm looking for a simple task mgmt / to-do list app that I can install on a private webserver and manage projects via browser.

Basically I'd like to be able to add & group tasks under different headings and check off items as they are completed.  This can be very basic - I do not require any support for multiple users, attachments or time tracking.

Anyone use something like this and/or have recommendations?

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. Especially point out your requirements, as your question currently is rather broad: structure? What makes a "project"? Simple check-list, or maybe possibility to include attachments, link to a calendar/phone book, ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [Tracks](http://www.getontracks.org/)? Seems to have all you need:

- able to add tasks and assign tasks to projects and tick them as they get completed,
- is web-based and self-hosted ("[Data is stored in a database (either MySQL, Postgresql or SQLite), and viewed in a web browser via a web server (Apache, Lighttpd or Mongrel among others).](http://www.getontracks.org/manual/)").

Have a look, maybe it can work for you.