# ToDo manager with dependencies and events

Tags: windows, gratis, project-management, todo

I am looking for a ToDo list application.

## Functional properties

**Required**

- some descriptive text per item
- zero to *n* other ToDo items the current item depends on
- state (open/done/disabled (while dependencies are not yet marked as *done*)) for each item
- optionally, a date at which the ToDo item is automatically marked as *done*

**Preferred**

- possibly allows to sort items by a user-assigned priority
- stores dates at which items were marked as *done*
- synchronization between different machines within LAN (i.e. not via a 3rd-party server on the web)

## Non-functional properties

**Required**

- runs on MS Windows 7 and above
- free of charge
- stores its data locally (i.e. does not require accessing any cloud)
- a somewhat usable, point-and-click-based way to see and edit which items are open, and which items depend on which other items

**Preferred**

- desktop application
- open source
- additional Android client with some synchronization capability (if possible, within LAN rather than going via an account somewhere on the web)
- also runnable on Linux or with a compatible Linux equivalent
- reasonably light-weight

**Undesirable, but accepted in absence of more suitable solutions**

- rather than a desktop application, runs on/creates its own server and can locally be accessed from within the browser

## Similar Questions

- [*TODO app with dependencies*](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/26194/todo-app-with-dependencies) - Primarily looks for an Android app.
- [*A todo app that allows specifying task duration and more*](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/17173/a-todo-app-that-allows-specifying-task-duration-and-more) - Focused on temporal planning, looking primarily for cloud-based or mobile software.
- [*Task manager with two-way Google Calendar sync*](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/2883/task-manager-with-two-way-google-calendar-sync?rq=1) - Focus on synchronization, no requirement of dependencies, looking for an Android app.
- [*https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/13704/task-mgmt-app-web-based-self-hosted*](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/13704/task-mgmt-app-web-based-self-hosted) - Question is quite vague and has no answers.
- [*Todo application for web or Linux machine*](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/19049/todo-application-for-web-or-linux-machine) - Primarily looking for Linux application, no requirement of dependencies.

## Ruled out Candidates

- [Task Coach](http://taskcoach.org/) - Does not support automatical closing of ToDo items by date.
- [Todoist](https://todoist.com/) - Cloud-based.
- [Wunderlist](https://www.wunderlist.com) - Cloud-based.
- [Wieldy](http://www.wieldy.de) - Does not allow for dependencies between tasks.

Comment: Very tough requirements. I doubt any tool fulfills them all. You might want to check http://orgmode.org - maybe with some scripting you can realize all you need. - Good Luck and let us know your solution!

Comment: Please have a look at this thread http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/27225/19820

Comment: If you'd be willing to host your own "service" for that, I'd watch out for DAV based solutions. Tasks are a sub of CalDAV (calendar via WebDAV).

Comment: what about self hosted ?

Comment: @Fawix: I already listed that option as a less desirable, yet (if there is nothing else) acceptable alternative: "rather than a desktop application, runs on/creates its own server and can locally be accessed from within the browser"

Comment: Ok, then this is a nice alternative: https://wekan.io/

Answer (score 2):

How about [ToDoList](http://abstractspoon.com/wiki/doku.php?id=start)? I find it to be quite powerful and although it does not cover everything you need, a good chunk of it is there:

- some descriptive text per item - **check**
- zero to n other ToDo items the current item depends on - **check**
- state (open/done/disabled (while dependencies are not yet marked as done)) - open/done states - **check**
- for each item optionally, a date at which the ToDo item is automatically marked as done - ***not sure***
- allows to sort items by a user-assigned priority - **check**
- stores dates at which items were marked as done - ***not sure***
- synchronization between different machines within LAN (i.e. not via a 3rd-party server on the web) - **should also be a [check](http://abstractspoon.com/wiki/doku.php?id=multi-user-prefs#simple_source_control)**
- runs on MS Windows 7 and above - **check**
- free of charge - **check**
- stores its data locally (i.e. does not require accessing any cloud) - **check**
- a somewhat usable, point-and-click-based way to see and edit which items are open, and which items depend on which other items - **check**
- desktop application - **check**
- open source - **check**
- additional Android client with some synchronization capability (if possible, within LAN rather than going via an account somewhere on the web) - **no**
- also runnable on Linux or with a compatible Linux equivalent - **I think it is a [check](http://abstractspoon.com/wiki/doku.php?id=linux) as well**
- reasonably light-weight - **check**

Maybe worth a look.

Comment: I have been using this for years, check regularly for something better, and find nothing. I heartily agree with this answer

Answer (score 1):

The **Task** and **To Do** areas of [Borg Calendar](https://mikeberger.github.io/borg_calendar/) could work. It can be configured to open to the Task manager (rather than the default Calendar) in the program options, and should handle almost all of OP's requirements:

### Functional properties

**Required**

- [image: Yes] some descriptive text per item
- [image: Yes] zero to *n* other ToDo items the current item depends on
- [image: Yes] state (open/done/disabled (while dependencies are not yet marked as *done*)) for each item
- [image: Note] NOT SURE | optionally, a date at which the ToDo item is automatically marked as *done*

**Preferred**

- [image: Yes] possibly allows to sort items by a user-assigned priority
- [image: Yes] stores dates at which items were marked as *done*
- [image: No] | DON'T THINK SO: MIGHT BE DONE USING OTHER TOOLS:`¹` synchronization between different machines within LAN (i.e. not via a 3rd-party server on the web)

<sup>`¹` Maybe rsync or something? I have used BORG with its data on e.g. Dropbox and that worked fine, but that's not what OP is after here.</sup>

### Non-functional properties

**Required**

- [image: Yes] runs on MS Windows 7 and above
- [image: Yes] free of charge
- [image: Yes] stores its data locally (i.e. does not require accessing any cloud)
- [image: Yes] a somewhat usable, point-and-click-based way to see and edit which items are open, and which items depend on which other items | [image: Note] IF I'VE UNDERSTOOD OP CORRECTLY! Would need to check this one.

**Preferred**

- [image: Yes] desktop application
- [image: Yes] open source
- [image: No] additional Android client with some synchronization capability (if possible, within LAN rather than going via an account somewhere on the web)
- [image: Yes] also runnable on Linux or with a compatible Linux equivalent
- [image: Yes] reasonably light-weight

### Screen shots

**Task Tree:**
[image: Task Tree]

**Task pane:**
[image: Task pane]

There is good guidance given in the bundled Help file on using these elements of the app. I have run BORG successfully on each of Windows 7, Ubuntu (18.04 LTS), and Mac OSX (Mojave).